# Gitlab Runner to run jobs on selected runners according to custom variable

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am planning to schedule jobs on runners based on variable from  pipeline web UI. I have two runners registered for a project and currently both are on same machine for now.Both runners are having the same tags so differentiation from tags is not possible too.

This is my yaml file

```yaml
stages :
  - common
  - specific
test1:
  stage: common
  tags:
    - runner
    - linux
  script:
    - echo $CI_RUNNER_DESCRIPTION
    - echo "This is run on all runners"
test2:
  stage: specific
  tags:
    - runner
    - linux
  script: echo "This is run on runner 1" 
  only:
    variables:
      - $num == $CI_RUNNER_DESCRIPTION

test3:
  stage: specific
  tags:
    - runner
    - linux
  script: echo "This is run on runner 2"
  only:
    variables:
      - $num == $CI_RUNNER_DESCRIPTION
```

So variable on which the selection happens is "num". The description of the runners can be 1 or 2.
The default value for num is 0 and according to variable passed from pipeline UI, the jobs are to be selected and run.
But when I execute the test with num 1 or 2, only test1 gets executed which is common to all runners.

Is such a implementation possible or am I facing issue because the runners are on same machine ?

Comment: Can't you add more tags?

Comment: @makozaki Yeah its possible but how should I change the yaml file so that gitlab runner can choose the jobs based on variables input too ?

Comment: I just tested on my side and it didn't work (my runners are on different machines). I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `variables only` is not the right approach to select runners. Right now you select one of the 2 runners and try not to execute job if runner description doesn't match. Even if this worked it wouldn't make much sense as you don't know if the job will be executed or not.
I suggest you add specific labels for runners and specify which job should run on which runner.

```yaml
test2:
  stage: specific
  tags:
    - runner_1
  script: echo "This is run on runner 1" 

test3:
  stage: specific
  tags:
    - runner_2
  script: echo "This is run on runner 2"
```

If you want to select runner for the job based on UI input, maybe you can add variable to tags section. To be honest I didn't test such solution and donno if it's gonna work. Yet still it would require to create specific tags for your runners.

```yaml
  tags:
    - $tag_variable_selected_from_UI
```

Comment: My idea was to keep the lines in my yaml file minimal even if I add more runners. But looks like the method with different tags would be the only way to do it.
As for the variable to tags method, it is still not yet implemented.
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/35742

Comment: If you have a lot of duplicated lines in your steps then you can extract them to yaml template and load it in each step.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this currently with gitlab. As you noted in your comment on the accepted answer, this will be available when https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/35742 is resolved.

That being said, while the "accepted" answer correctly states "only" is the incorrect way to do this, it suggests another way that also doesnt work.

Once [dynamic tagging](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/35742) support is added into gitlab-ci, this will be possible. Currently, the solution is to provide unique jobs each with their own tags.

Depending on what exactly you are trying to accomplish, you can keep your code as DRY as possible for now by adding job templates in combination with [extends](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends) to reduce duplication to a couple of lines per job.